# Open PDF in seprate windows

Tags: jquery, pdf, export-to-pdf

I try to Download/open PDF file in separate window but currently PDF file is open in same window

this is what i try

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      //$(function sumdata() {
      function mypdf() {

          $('#tabledata').tableExport({ type: 'pdf', escape: 'false' });
          window.open(mypdf);
      }
      //});

       </script>
<a  href="#"    id="pdf" onclick="mypdf()"   style="background-color: #3399FF;color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;display:none;font-size: medium;PADDING: 15px;margin: 12px;"">EXPORT TO PDF</a>
```

when i try this `window.open(mypdf,'_blank')` this show an error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:33578/function mypdf() { $('
Physical Path      C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MIS\chart_project\chart_project\function mypdf() { $('
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\CHART_PROJECT

More Information:
This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.
View more information »
```

table export js 
check this link

[table export](http://pastebin.com/FiWKqCEg)

Comment: You want your PDF document to open in the PDF viewer, not the web browser? This is an OS setting, not something that can be coded. You need to open up your PDF viewer and find an option in there to not open in the browser. This is old but you get the idea: http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/08/how_do_i_open_a_pdf_in_acrobat_i/

Comment: but when i  send project to client then i think they can not prefer these setting.. i have table and there is button and i just want when i click on that button then pdf open in new tab

Comment: As far as I know you can't tell a link to open in a new tab, a new window or the client application from javascript. That is decided _outside_ in the browser or the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document

```
<a  href="#"  target="_blank"   id="pdf" onclick="mypdf()"   style="background-color: #3399FF;color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;display:none;font-size: medium;PADDING: 15px;margin: 12px;"">EXPORT TO PDF</a>
```

otherwise use

```
var url = "Your link";    
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: There is webform and in that there is button when i click on button then same webform open in 2nd tab and pdf  open in first tab

Comment: try this window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: with "your link" replace which link i add?
"

Comment: i think i already told in question that when i try this show an error

Comment: Try this without any script <a  href="#" target="_blank"   id="pdf" onClick ="$('#tabledata').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120384/discussion-between-bhupesh-kushwaha-and-user6628729).

Comment: hy when i try this open webform page in another window not pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the table export does not support the openning in new page option. By default, this plugin uses window.open function but does not specify a target:

```
defaults.type == 'csv' || defaults.type == 'txt'
window.open('data:application/'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData;' + base64data);
...
defaults.type == 'sql'
window.open('data:application/sql;filename=exportData;' + base64data);
.....
```

You can try to extend the default behavior and add a target option for the window. With the code you are using it will never open a new window since this behavior is done within the plugin and not from the place you are calling it.

**EDIT**

```
var defaults = {
                        separator: ',',
                        ignoreColumn: [],
                        tableName:'yourTableName',
                        type:'csv',
                        pdfFontSize:14,
                        pdfLeftMargin:20,
                        escape:'true',
                        htmlContent:'false',
                        consoleLog:'false',
                        // add the target to the options
                        target:'_blank'
                };
```

Then add it to all the window.open calls:

```
 window.open('data:application/'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData;' + base64data,
 defaults.target);
```

This is not tested, and you have to add it within the tableExport.js

Comment: where i add target option ? in tableexport?

Comment: you can add it to the default options in tableexport and pass it to the window.open function within the js file

Comment: this open in same page :(